# Use my class rather than from a JAR

Tags: java, class, classloader

I have a class `com.example.TestClass` which is in a JAR archive. Now, in my project (which uses the aforementioned JAR) I want to use a modified version of the class.

What I have tried so far was to create the very same class and package in my project's `src` directory, because I was hoping that it would be used during class loading, but unfortunately, that didn't work.

I have read about Javaassist, but I only want to restort to it unless absolutely necessary.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: well you can certainly create the class but in a different package, or create a subclass of the same or even create jar with updated code and version number

Comment: Subclassing is not an option, because I want to basically use my version of the test class, even in the JAR.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Check the order of the imports in your project.

Comment: Seen this: [How to load Different versions of the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759414/java-how-to-load-different-versions-of-the-same-class/11759613#11759613) ?

Comment: Let me understand your problem.You have 2 versions of the same class in your classpath and you want to load a particular version among them. Is this you require ?

Comment: @TomSebastian, exactly.

Comment: you can refer https://dzone.com/articles/java-classloader-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with your class path order.

### Changing the classpath order in Eclipse

- Go into your **Project Properties** > **Build Path**.
- In the **Order and Export** tab, find your `src` folder and press the **Up** button to move it higher up in the class path order. Keep pressing **Up** until it is above your JAR.
- Press **OK**.

### Changing the classpath order in Intellij IDEA

- Open **Project Structure** (either **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S** or **File** > **Project Structure**).
- Select **Modules** on the left, under **Project Settings**.
- Select the module in question in the middle pane.
- Arrange the order of the dependencies lists. Be sure your `Module Source` is above the other dependencies.

Comment: I had the right order, but had to move the source below my libs, then move it again above the libraries and rebuild everything. Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make sure that you TestClass is first on the classpath.
Take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html