# Does the JVM make any guarantees when a class will be unloaded?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

According to [JLS §12.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7) a class can be unloaded once its class loader can be reclaimed by Garbage Collection. This works in my implementation of a dynamic class loader. However, I would like to know for sure when a class has been unloaded by the GC. Can I force the GC to reclaim unused class loaders and would that simultaneously unload its previously loaded classes?

Incosistent GC behavior could cause some problems in my code.

Comment: In a word, no. "Incosistent GC behavior could cause some problems in my code." You should *never* be relying on GC behavior for correct functioning of your code. The only guarantee is that memory is GC'd immediately, later or never.

Comment: This feels like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @AndyTurner I am creating a system for dynamically loading/unloading classes to hotswap plugins on runtime. I unload classes by closing its class loader and not referencing it anywhere. However the unloading is all predicated on the GC actually cleaning up the class loader. Essentially I want to know what steps I could take to guarantee the GC actually unloads those classes. I could possibly wait until findLoadedClass(className) in the System class loader returns null... But it's a suboptimal solution.

Comment: Why do you care about when the classes are unloaded, though?

Comment: Because to "hotswap" or load a new version of said class, it must first be unloaded. As far as I know, I can't have two versions of the same class file loaded simultaneously.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759414/java-how-to-load-different-versions-of-the-same-class#:~:text=The%20normal%20thing%20is%20classes,classes%20must%20not%20be%20there.

Comment: This seems to be an appropriate solution, thank you!

Comment: Like with every garbage collection: no, you can’t reliably force it. But if the classes are unreachable, there is no reason why it should make a difference whether they are actually unloaded or not.